# Django datetime comparison

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to find records in a Django app where a datetime field is older than the current datetime.

I have something like this:

```
records = Record.objects.filter(my_field__lte=datetime.now())
```

However, it only finds records where the date is older than today (if there are records older than now but on today's date, they are not returned.)

Edit: Just to clarify.  If the field is set to 19:59:00 12-10-2011 and the current time is 20:00:00 12-10-2011, then I would want this record to be returned in the queryset.  However, it's not actually being returned until the query is run on the following day.  (It's run every five minutes on a cronscript and is used to send emails based on this datetime field)

Hope that clears it up.

BTW, I am using MySQL

Can anyone help?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I can hardly understand what you're asking. My guess is this: You're using a DateField and querying for `my_field__lt` instead of `my_field__lte`.

Comment: What storage engine are you using?

Comment: What in the world does the storage engine have to do with anything?

Comment: @Dan: How does your current code not work? 19:59 is less than or equal to 20:00.

Comment: If he knew why it was not working, I'm sure he would not be posting the question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

check in database if you can see time attributes, next check if you have models.DateTimeField in your models and no models.DateField by error

Answer (score 0):

Just test for midnight tomorrow instead of now:

```
now = datetime.now()
midnight = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day+1, 0, 0, 0)

records = Record.objects.filter(my_field__lt=midnight)
```

Or you can use `date.today` and `timedelta` to get the same effect:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

tomorrow = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
records = Record.objects.filter(my_field__lt=tomorrow)
```

Comment: This fails to answer the question.

Comment: He wants records that are older than now but still "today". This answers the question perfectly.

Comment: No, he wants records that are older than the current datetime right NOW (such as, all records before 5pm today, but not after 5pm today).  Not all records from today.

Comment: His current code already does that, yet he's here asking for help. I don't even think he knows what he wants, so it's pointless to argue. It's different interpretations of a poorly asked question.

Comment: Yeah, his code does in fact do that but he's not getting the expected output which is why he is here. This is why I asked what storage engine he was using (perhaps a limitation of date comparison on that level).

Comment: `midnight = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day+1, 0, 0, 0)` on the last day of the month?